# Jquery mobile dynamic view lose format css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I have a problem with my js code.
When i dynamically load  in my page i lose format.

```
<div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <fieldset class="ui-field-contain">
        <label for="tav">Tavolo:</label>
        <select id="tav" data-native-menu="false">

        </select>
    </fieldset><
</div>
```

this is my js, that get json object from ajax call.

```
$.each(result, function(i, data) {  
    $("#tav").append('<option value="'+data.ID+'">'+data.Descr+'</option>');
});
```

How can i format them?

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean you lose format?

Comment: Lose jquery css style.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only dynamically updating the SELECT widget, call **[Refresh](http://api.jquerymobile.com/selectmenu/#method-refresh)** on the widget:

```
$.each(result, function(i, data) {  
    $("#tav").append('<option value="'+data.ID+'">'+data.Descr+'</option>');
});
$("#tav").selectmenu( "refresh", true );
```

Better yet

```
var allOpts = '';
$.each(result, function(i, data) {  
    allOpts += '<option value="'+data.ID+'">'+data.Descr+'</option>');
});
$("#tav").append(allOpts).selectmenu( "refresh", true );
```

If more widgets on the page are dynamically loaded, call enhanceWithin() on the page or container, e.g.

```
$(".ui-content").enhanceWithin();
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I Tried both method.  And yes other components are loaded dynamically on my page. How should i use that function?

Comment: data-native-menu="false" is ignored within a popup because jQM does not support popups on top of popups. Other than that my code should work: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/h3J8j/2/

Comment: I'll try in some hours. Now i'm not at home. Thanks